# how to interpret .!application.!canvas.! demonstrated by self.master.focus_get() tkinter

Tags: tkinter, widget

When I click on my textbox and then click on my canvas, something with text variable seems to be retained by the following method.

```py
def reinitscroll(self, event):
    self.addScroll()
    self.onEnter(event)
    self.master.focus_get()
    print(self.master.focus_get())
```

My shell display :

```
.!application.!canvas.!text15
```

or if there is nothing, it show me a simple point such as :

```
.
```

I do not understand what this corresponds to and how to go further to understand how to use :

```py
print(self.master.focus())
```

and

```py
print(self.master.focus_get())
```

or

```py
print(something attached to a widget)
```

Could someone help me to understand that?

Answer (score 1):

A string like `.!application.!canvas.!text15` corresponds to the internal name of a widget, which is what tkinter returns when a widget is converted to a string.

Tkinter is based on tk, which is a GUI library built for the tcl programming language. In tk (and tkinter) widgets live in a hierarchy. The root window is named "." similar to how the root directory of your computer may be named "/". Widget names are separated by additional periods, just as filenames use "/" to separate folder and file names.

So, "." represents the root window. If you create a frame in that widget with the name "frame1" the internal name will be ".frame1". If you put a button in that frame with the name "button" the internal name will be ".frame1.button1".

In your case you have `.!application.!canvas.!text15`. That means you have a root window (the leading "."), a window internally named "!application" with a widget inside it named "!canvas" and inside of that a widget named "!text15".

Almost without exception, you can completely ignore these internal names. Knowing them is largely only useful for understanding error messages which show the internal name rather than a python variable name.

When you do something like this:

```
print(self.master.focus_get())
```

You are first calling `self.master.focus_get()` which will return a reference to an actual widget. When you pass that to `print`, the widget reference is converted to a string, and for tkinter the string representation of a widget will be its internal tk name.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations Bryan, it helped me understand. But I'm also a little sad that we can't go further with these internal names.

Comment: @koalatree: what do you mean? There are ways to use them, but using built-in tkinter features is usually easier. What are you wanting to do? You can specify your own names, and convert widget ids to widget objects. I can’t imagine what else you want to do.

Comment: It seems strange, but the focus of the textbox which is in another script was carried over to my entire canvas as soon as I clicked on the textbox. I could click next to it (in the canvas but nothing changed). When I introduced self.master.focus(), I did not have this problem anymore. I specify that the text variable has the self.textbox.config(state='normal').